# Disable AutoRun and AutoPlay in windows 7 and 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, security, usb-flash-drive, virus

I read some old articles regarding the issue. I didn't found recent ones.
most of them talk about windows 7 or earlier windows.

I'm using windows 10 1067 latest build.
I have disabled AutoPlay from group policy.

What I'm not sure about is does this also disable AutoRun (autorun.ini)..?
I'm afraid of USB drives having autorun viruses and was hoping to disable autorun.

I have avast antivirus installed but prevention is better than medicine so hoping for an answer.

If the group policy AutoPlay isn't enough what should I do?
I am hoping for answer for both windows 7 & 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Autorun.inf` is [already disabled for several years](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/967715) in Windows (XP, Vista and later) to prevent malware spreed via USB flash drives.

Comment: Okay, Relief. So there is no way for any USB virus to auto execute unless explicitly invoked by opening the virus file. Right?

Comment: @Bsienn "no way" is a astrong statement, see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8224/73556